# Ventilation for Garage below house

Tags: garage, ventilation, building-regulations, uk

We have built a garage into our new build 4 story town house (garage and upper floor plans attached) which sits below the main house in its foot print. The floor above the garage is beam and block with a 50mm screed. What type of ventilation do we require for the garage? The two rear windows were due to be vents but we opted for closed windows so we could make more use of the garage space at the back. We will, im sure, due to building regs requirements need ventilation on this floor but what type of system would be suitable to remove the car fumes? The Floor space of the garage is 74m2. It's a UK build.

[image: Undercroft Garage, 600mm below ground, so 70% of the garage is above ground]

[image: Floor above garage]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need a lot more information: what is this "new build"? What's between the garage and the house? Is this all to be built, or is this some sort of retrofit? Etc. etc. etc....

Comment: @DanielGriscom, i have added some more details.